# Finding best polynomial approximation for function with complicated form and many terms

Tags: plotting, fitting, approximation

I have a function that contains 50 terms hence, it is a complicated-looking function. Now I expected it to be a polynomial function. How can I get this polynomial fit provided I don't have data, I have a complicated looking function that contains exponential terms.

Comment: This question is too abstract to be answered here. Please include example data so people can experiment and propose good solutions.

Comment: @Roman, while I agree that the question is substandard, in the sense that it neither provides context nor shows any due diligence, code attempts or examples of expected outcomes, I think it can be answered in abstract terms.

Comment: @RISHAVSAGAR Welcome to Mma.SE! Your question needs more from your side. Here it's considered helpful and polite to show your own efforts and share your data and code attempts in a well [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit your question](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) accordingly. Also, please take the [tour], it will help you understand the site. If you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) it will inspire great answers. In the current form, your question may be closed as off-topic, please [edit]

Comment: @rhermans in abstract terms I would argue that polynomial fits are a bad idea because it is very tricky to get the polynomial order right: too low, you get a bad fit; too high, you get oscillations. In general, there is no good answer here and everything depends on the concrete situation. Fitting is much more than plugging in numbers and requires a bit of experience with statistical concepts.

Answer (score 1):

The process is simple but the constructs are not for new users.  First define the function in terms of say f[x_].  Then generate a table of points {{x1,f(x1)},...{xn,f(xn)}}.  Then use `Fit` supplying the degree of the polynomial and the variable.  Below I supplied a 10 degree polynomial.  Fit then returns a fit function which I called `theFit`.  Then can compare the original function (the gray plot) to the fit function (red-dash) graphically.

```
 f[x_] := Sin[x] Exp[-x];
p1 = Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}];

theTable = Table[
   {x, f[x]},
   {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];
thePoly = Table[ x^i, {i, 0, 10}]
theFit = Fit[theTable, thePoly, x]
p2 = Plot[theFit, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}];
Show[{p1, p2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't give enough information, I would have been tempted to ignore the question, but given that you already getting answers, I will share something that may help.

As I see it, you don't have data to fit, but an analytical expression to approximate. Clearly, one option is @josh's answer, to use your analytical expression to create a table of data and then fit it into a function. I think you can go directly from one analytical expression to the polynomial.

If you care to approximate only on a point, then use [`Series`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html) to obtain a [Taylor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) power series expansion for $f(x)$ about the point $x=x_o$ to order $(x-x_o)^n$, where $n$ is an explicit integer.

```
Series[f[x], {x, xo, n}]
```

If you want to approximate over an interval, check the [Function Approximations Package](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FunctionApproximations/tutorial/FunctionApproximations.html), in the interval $[a,b]$ you can get a polynomial of degree $n$ using

```
Needs["FunctionApproximations`"]
EconomizedRationalApproximation[f[x], {x, {a, b}, n,0}]
```

[`EconomizedRationalApproximation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EconomizedRationalApproximation.html) finds the [*Padé* approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) about the midpoint of the interval $[a,b]$, and then perturbs the approximant with [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) to reduce the leading coefficient in the error.